# CentOS rsync directory contents but not directory?

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I'm trying to get the contents of /deploy/ to populate to /panda/ but it doesn't seem to work. I searched on here and found instruction to leave the trailing slashes; however each time I run it a blank-named directory is created within /panda/ (so /panda/ /) that contains the contents of /deploy/ but I am trying to get this to occur without it creating a new directory . I would like the contents of /deploy/ to override the contents of /panda/

This is the code I am currently using:

```
rsync -ahrvz /home/jellywhat/public_html/deploy/ /home/jellywhat/public_html/panda/
```

I do not get a 'deploy' directory inside of /panda, I simply get a directory with a blank name, containing the contents of /deploy/

[image: blank folder]

I tried removing the trailing slash on the receiving directory...

```
rsync -ahrvz /home/jellywhat/public_html/deploy/ /home/jellywhat/public_html/panda
```

This seemingly does nothing. I get an email with the file list, which is correct, and includes FileA.php, a specific file I am using as a reference, but FileA.php which is located under /deploy/cfx_controllers/ is not being copied to /panda/cfx_controllers/ even though it is the most recent file modified and does not exist under /panda/cfx_controllers/

**UPDATE: 1:51PM**

It actually is 'working;' it is not updating the existing panda directory , it is making an entirely new one:

[image: folder duplication]

How can I get it to 'update' the 'existing' directory without this occurring?

**UPDATE: 2:36PM**

I tried the receiving directory with and without a slash. With a slash, it creates a duplicate directory in the parent directory. Without a slash, it places the contents of /deploy/ inside of a seemingly unnamed folder.

[image]

Does anyone have any guidance on where I am failing to get this deployment script to actually deploy the files?

Comment: Still doing research; I am not concerned with 'if a file is removed from deploy, it needs to be removed from panda' and only concerned with 'every file inside deploy must exist inside panda.'

Comment: I also cannot delete the contents of panda before import, as there are numerous other folders (that do NOT exist within deploy) that don't need to be modified at all. I suppose I could do delete/imports for every folder, but this seems a bit cumbersome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will copy the contents of `deploy` (but not the directory name itself) into the existing target directory `panda`:

```
rsync -ahrvz /home/jellywhat/public_html/deploy/ /home/jellywhat/public_html/panda/
```

The trailing slash on the source directory tells `rsync` to copy the directory contents without the directory name itself. The trailing slash on the destination directory is irrelevant. If the copy doesn't work like this for you then you haven't entered the command exactly as you have written in your question.

Note that there's no point using `-z` as you cannot compress files during a local copy. Also, the `-r` is implied by `-a` so it can be omitted.

---

Um, this file that you now say you're creating to contain the command. If you created it on a Windows system please ensure you transferred it as a text file and not a binary file. Otherwise the file line endings will get badly in the way.

Comment: I believe your suggestion of the file line endings was the key; I deleted the file I was using and created a new one within linux and it appears to be working now. Thank you for your guidance and explanation on what was going on!

Answer (score 0):

There are no "directories with empty names" (or files, for that matter) in Linux, you probably have some garbage (that prints as nothing) at the end of the command. Note that you *can* have a file named `a file name<move back to beginning of line><erase to end of line>` (here `<...>` is a sequence of characters that tell your terminal to do as directed). You don't *see* anything, but there is a name there. Infinite fun to be had of newbies ;-)

`rsync` is *very* picky on slashes at the end (there really isn't any other reasonable way to tell the program what it should do), read the manual carefully.

Comment: I'm really trying here. I made a brand new .sh file through putty containing only the one command. The first try, I did not put a slash on the receiving directory. This created a duplicate /panda directory. The second time, I added the slash but then it put it inside of the 'garbage' directory with the deploy files inside of it. https://i.imgur.com/C1ZOnCB.jpg